# Elasticsearch in Azure with logs in multiple regions?

Tags: azure, elasticsearch

we are cloud based (only Azure so far) company and we would like to analyze logs from all our VMs, apps, etc. We are looking to deploy Elasticsearch in Azure. But because we have many regions I wonder what would be the best approach to do that given that there is no peering between Azure regions (well, peering virtual networks in different regions is currently in preview so we cannot use it at the moment). So it looks like we have the following options:

- use VPN between regions and have one ELK stack deployed (how about cost of shipping all the logs over VPN ?)
- deploy ELK stack in every region and use VNet peering

So what do you guys choose when you want to deploy multi region log analysis in ELK ?

Comment: how about oms? have you considered that?

Comment: What would be an advantage of using OMS vs ELK ?

Comment: no management overhead, probably costs less (no need to pay for elk vms), monitors Azure PaaS natively

Comment: Are you using it ?

Comment: i was\is\will be, why?

Comment: Just asking if this is your personal experience. Did you use both ELK and OMS ?

Comment: only oms, unfortunately